# Spring Mvc: getting session attributes accross different methods in the same Controller

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, session

Please bear with my limited knowlodge of spring MVC, still trying to learn how it works.

My issue is as follows: I'm working on a simple guessing game, in which you would pick a letter from a dropdown select option, and refresh the same view with updated info on how many guesses you made.

Game (model class)

```
public class Game {

    private Player player;
    private Language language;  
    private Random randomGenerator;

    private List<String> dictionary;
    private char[] selectedWord;
```

with its respective getters/setters and such.

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"game"})
public class SimpleController {

@Autowired
private SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver;

private LoginValidator loginValidator;
private GameValidator gameValidator;

@Autowired
public void setLoginValidator(LoginValidator loginValidator) {
    this.loginValidator = loginValidator;
}

@Autowired
public void setGameValidator(GameValidator gameValidator) {
    this.gameValidator = gameValidator;
}   


@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView init(ModelMap model) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/views/login.jsp");
    LoginBean loginBean = new LoginBean();
    model.addAttribute("game", new Game());
    model.addAttribute("ENGLISH", Language.ENGLISH);
    model.addAttribute("SPANISH", Language.SPANISH);

    mav.addObject("LoginBean", loginBean);
    return mav;

}

@RequestMapping (value="/processLogin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String login (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @ModelAttribute("LoginBean") LoginBean loginBean, 
        @ModelAttribute("Game") Game game,
        BindingResult result, 
        SessionStatus status, ModelMap model) {

    /* I'm aware I would need a validator of some sort, but for now I'm trying to get this to work without one*/


    if (loginBean.getLanguage() == Language.ENGLISH) {          
        localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale("EN"));
    }
    else{
        localeResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale("ES"));
    }

    loginBean.setDictionary(FileLoader.loadDictionary(loginBean.getLanguage()));        

    game.setPlayer(loginBean.getPlayer());
    game.setLanguage(loginBean.getLanguage());
    game.setDictionary(loginBean.getDictionary());
    game.setSelectedWord(game.getRandomWord(game.getDictionary()));


    model.addAttribute("Game", game);
    request.getSession().setAttribute("game", game);

    System.out.println(game.getSelectedWord());
    return "redirect:/index.htm";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView play(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session,
        @ModelAttribute("Game") Game game) {

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/views/index.jsp");

    if(session.getAttribute("game") != null) {
        System.out.println("finding session attributes");
        game = (Game)session.getAttribute("game");
        mav.addObject("game", game);        
    } else {
        System.out.println("no luck finding those");
    }

    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping (value="/guessLetter", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String guessLetter (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        HttpSession session, @ModelAttribute("Game") Game game) {


    if(session.getAttribute("game") != null) {
        System.out.println("ESTOY buscando session attr mietras adivino");
        game = (Game)session.getAttribute("game");          
        System.out.println("guess?" + game.getGuess());
    } else {
        System.out.println("nothing gets here");
    }       

    return "redirect:/index.htm";

}



}
```

Please let me know if i need to update the question with some more info

Comment: `@ModelAttribute("Game")` simply doesn't match the name in `@SessionAttributes("game")` and thus isn't stored and retrieved from the session.

Comment: @M.Deinum that was it! Thank you! If you post it as an answer i'll check it as the correct one.

Comment: Due to the nature of the answer I voted for a closure of the question, as it was just a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a session scope bean class where you can keep all necessary attributes.

When the bean is `@Autowired` in your controller you can get/set all the fields you need from any method of the controller.

Just annotate the Game  as `@Component` and autowire it rather than manually create it.